# Can I track the matches played on Black Ops 2 on the PC?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I was wondering if this is possible without Steam, like the Elite/HQ function for the PS3 and Xbox. Simply on a website or something. 
To elaborate my question: I am looking for a website of some sort to track my played matches, k/d, accuracy etc.

Comment: added new answer

Answer (score 1):

After further research and a lot of time scanning websites I have concluded that there is no website that you can track to help you. The steam site has no coordination with outside web sources and because of that will not share information with another web address or organization.

Comment: seeing as there is still no other answer i will give you the reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

On the Elite section of the Call of Duty website you can find previous matches, k/d, heat maps, your gun stats, and etcetra.